# setTimeout alternative

Tags: javascript

I want to run a function after delay a second , setTimeout works on browser, but on ipad, it sometimes just completely skip this function, perhaps it can't run several setTimeout at the same time becuase I have many other timeout functions, what is the proper alternative for setTimeout?

```
that.movepictimer = setTimeout(function(){
                    for(i=1;i<that.pic.length;i++){
                        if(that.$pic[i]!=null && that.$pic[i]!=undefined){
                            css_translate(f,that.$pic[i],that.picleft,0,i);
                        }
                    }
                },1000)
```

Comment: Try declaring `i` as a local variable with `var` as in `for ( var i = 1; ... )`. In your code `i` is global and could cause problems...

Comment: what does it has to do with jquery ?

Comment: i always thought i in the for loop is local...

Comment: Always use `var` even in `for` loops. If you've been using global `i`s in your code that could be the root of the problem. I've seen strange things happen before because of this.

Comment: *becuase I have many other timeout functions* You should probably try to fix *that* first. Over relying on something like `setTimeout` or it's mildly different cousin `setInteval` just isn't good habit.

Comment: @FatDogMark—Javascript has three scopes: global, function and eval, there is no block scope. You only care about the first two. Any variable that isn't declared with var becomes a global variable at the point it is assigned a value.

Comment: @RobG What's `eval` scope? `eval` just takes whatever scope you're in

Comment: as others said: variable i being global can cause what you call "completely skip this function"

Comment: so the correct way should be for(var i=0;i<something;i++) ??? var inside for would be good?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript isn't multithreaded, so methods setTimeout and setInterval don't guarantee execution in certain time. Try to use Chrome Javascript CPU Profiler to find performance issues in code.